# C# - "Illegal Characters in Path" File.ReadAllLines

Tags: c#, parsing, path

```
    public void LoadRegionMaps()
    {
        for (int x = 9; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 9; y < 10; y++)
            {
                string path = RegionData[x, y, 1];
                System.Console.Write("Opening File...");

                if(path != "0")
                {
                    System.Console.Write(path);
                    string[] fileText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

The paths in the .txt file look like this:

```
"..\\Bin\\Assets\\WorldMap\\Regions\\Forest.txt"
```

I've tried changing it to

```
@"..\\Bin\\Assets\\WorldMap\\Regions\\Forest.txt"
```

Neither work.

Both result in the error in the title, during the last line of code I showed.

```
path = "..\\Bin\\Assets\\WorldMap\\Regions\\Forest.txt"
```

Works.

RegionData is a string array, holding the above filepaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double `\\` on the file and the `"`.  `\\` is a escape sequence that translates to `\` on C#, but that does not apply to data read from a file unless you code for that.

```
..\Bin\Assets\WorldMap\Regions\Forest.txt
```

Comment: Oh glorious glorious C# :) I was able to  get rid of the entire path and simply use 1 variable the name (ex "Forest") and get rid of "..\path\path\path\Forest.txt" and "..\path\Forest.png". I hate C++ strings lol :P this is wonderful! path = ("..\\Bin\\Assets\\WorldMap\\Regions\\" + path + ".txt");